# Does JdbcBatchItemWriter do not support input item as List<Map> ?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

From the ItemWriter interface which JdbcBatchItemWriter implemented

```
public interface ItemWriter<T> {
    void write(List<? extends T> items) throws Exception;
}
```

It think is designed for batch update, but what if the item I used as input is already a List or List, do I have to write my own JdbcItemWriter, or the built-in JdbcBatchItemWriter could do the work?

Comment: Did you figure out how to write a `List<List<String>>` using `ItemPreparedStatementSetter` or `JdbcBatchItemWriter` ? If yes can you pls share how did you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built in `JdbcBatchItemWriter` will work.  You're item is of type `List`.  There's nothing wrong with that.  You'll just need to implement the appropriate `ItemPreparedStatementSetter` or `ItemSqlParameterSourceProvider` yourself to map the elements of the `List` to the values in the SQL.

Comment: I see the point, my item is of type List, the writer method of JdbcBatchItemWriter will take a List<List> as input. if i use itemSqlParameterSourceProvider, then the implementation of itemSqlParameterSourceProvider will be a little tricky, according to the source code of JdbcBatchItemWriter: [  batchArgs[i++] = itemSqlParameterSourceProvider.createSqlParameterSource(item); ]   in this line, the item is a type of List, not a Map or a Bean.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.
Use a domain object contains a list.

```
class MyDomainObject {
  List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
}
```

and `T` substitution produce

```
public class MyItemWrite implement ItemWrite<MyDomainObject> {
  public void write(List<? extends MyDomainObject> items) throws Exception {
    for(MyDomainObject o : items)
    {
      // Perform o.items write
    }
  }
}
```